# Can't acess .Android folder from windows CMD

Tags: android, cmd

I am trying to get my Android hash key, but I can't even access my .Android folder where the debug.ketstore is located. When I paste the directory, directly into CMD, then press enter, I get the following error: `"C:\Users\Jack\.android" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Would anyone know why this happening?

Comment: try `cd` to switch directory...

Comment: As shem said, start at the root directory c:\, then cd into each folder one at a time. You'll find the issue that way.  If you need to see directories use DIR /ad